# Vue 3 Как передавать реактивный объект в компонент и обратно

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vue3

Есть обычный родительский компонент. Который должен передавать в дочерний компонент некий  реактивный объект и получать обратно при изменении.

```
<template>
  <section>
      <cl-component v-model="data"></cl-component >
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const data= reactive({
      HH: "09",
      MM: "50",
    })

    return {
      data,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Дочерний компонент. Который выводит список времени. При нажатии на ячейку времени, срабатывает функция selectTime. Как вернуть эти данные обратно в родителя?

```
<template>
  ....
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {
          HH: "00",
          MM: "00",
        }
      },
    },
  },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  setup(props, context) {
    const hour = ref("" as string)
    const minute = ref("" as string)
   
    const selectTime = (type: string, value: string) => {
      // ...
      hour.value = value
      // ...
      minute.value = value

      //context.emit("update:modelValue", {???????})
    }

 
    return {
      hour,
      minute,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Vue3, вы можете использовать [аргумент директивы](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/v-model.html#v-model-arguments) `v-model`, это позволит иметь несколько двухсторонних привязок `v-model` на пользовательском компоненте как альтернатива использования объекта.

В дочернем компоненте можно создать собственные `v-model`, потому как нельзя изменять значения свойств из`props` прямой манипуляцией (связано это с односторонней привязкой), допустим следующего вида:

```
const hourValue = Vue.computed({
      get: () => props.hour,
      set: (val) => {
        h.value = val
        context.emit('update:hour', val < 10 ? `0${val}` : val)
      },
    })
```

и после этого достаточно назначить элементу, отвечающему за выбор времени это вычисляемое свойство как `v-model`,

```
<input type="range" v-model="hourValue" min="00" max="23" step="1">
```

Пример использования данного подхода

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    time: {
      HH: "10",
      MM: "00",
    }
  }),
  template: `
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Родительский компонент</legend>
  <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
  <v-timing v-model:hour="time.HH" v-model:minute="time.MM"></v-timing>
  </fieldset>
    `
});

app.component('v-timing', {
  props: {
    minute: {
      type: String,
      default: "00",
    },
    hour: {
      type: String,
      default: "00",
    },
  },
  emits: ["update:minute", "update:hour"],
  setup(props, context) {

    const h = Vue.ref(props.hour)
    const m = Vue.ref(props.minute)

    const hourValue = Vue.computed({
      get: () => props.hour,
      set: (val) => {
        h.value = val
        context.emit('update:hour', val < 10 ? `0${val}` : val)
      },
    })

    const minuteValue = Vue.computed({
      get: () => props.minute,
      set: (val) => {
        m.value = val
        context.emit('update:minute', val < 10 ? `0${val}` : val)
      },
    })

    return {
      minuteValue,
      hourValue,
      h,
      m,
    }
  },
  template: `
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Дочерний компонент</legend>
  Час = <input type="range" v-model="hourValue" min="00" max="23" step="1">
  Минута = 
  <input type="range" v-model="minuteValue" min="00" max="59" step="5">
  <hr>
  Выберите час
  <div class="flex">
    <template v-for="i in 23">
      <div :class="['box', { active: i == h}]" @click="hourValue=i.toString()">{{i}}</div>
    </template>
  </div>
  Выберите минуту
  <div class="flex">
    <template v-for="i in [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50]">
      <div :class="['box', { active: i == m}]" @click="minuteValue=i.toString()">{{i}}</div>
    </template>
  </div>
  </fieldset>`
});


app.mount('#app');
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #42b983;
}

.box:hover,
.box.active {
  background: #7d7dd7;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```